# Sending data from js to html with ejs components

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ejs

I've just begun to learn about JS and node.js. I've been trying to do some practicing on sending data from a DB in MySQL to the html via ejs components. I tried using ejs.render(data, {data: something_from_DB}); to send fetched information(something_from_DB), identified by "data". I then used the identifier "data" in the ejs code in html, but it'd complain that data is not defined in the html file.

Here's the js code.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var app = express();
app.use(app.router);

var client = mysql.createConnection({
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database_name'
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    fs.readFile('list.html', 'utf8', function(error, data){
        client.query('SELECT * FROM test_table', function(error, results){
            console.log(results);
            res.send(ejs.render(data), {data: results});
        });
    });
});
```

And here's the portion from list.html

```
<% data.forEach(function(item, index){ %>
<tr>
    <td><%= item.id %></td>
    <td><%= item.name %></td>
    <td><%= item.phone_no %></td>
</tr>
<% }); %>
```

When I print the results, I get:

```
[ RowDataPacket { id: 1, name: 'PETER', phone_no: '0100000000' } ]
```

which looks fine. I'm looking to pass this with "data" but I don't think this is happening.

Please do correct me if I'm using words that are out of context.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is simple mistake.Just try this .

```
      res.render('ejs file name',{data: results,});
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to a question, should be a comment. Please see [When should I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).